# Referencing classes and namespace confusion

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I have 2 class libraries (ie ABC and XYZ and XYZ is dependent on ABC).  Both have a class called Utilities.

In a Class in XYZ, I attempt to make a reference to ABC.Utilities, but I get a compile error saying it doesn't exist.

For example:
`ABC.Utilities.SomeMethod()`

When I view the error tool tip, I notice that it is attempting to reference a namespace of XYZ.ABC and "Utilities is not a member of XYZ.ABC"  Which is true!

But Visual Studio is for some reason, implicitly attempting to add the current namespace to the one I've attempted to declare.

Note: The build order is fine.
Note2: I realize I can use the global scope
Note3: The codebase compiles/works on VS 2010 and compiled in .NET 2.0. And I'm just porting this to VS2015 and trying to get it to compile/work on .net 4.x.

Any ideas on why there's this confusion/ambiguity?

thanks in advance

Comment: Try making the classes private.

Comment: I'm trying to use the class outside of itself.  I need to use the ABC.Utilities class from a class in XYZ.

Comment: Smells like a Roslyn bug, there have been many.  Best to report it with the project, but you'll have to do a better job of showing repro code.